# Error handling with Android architecture components and MVVM

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have read the android guide to Architecture here:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

I am using this architecture in my project but I have no idea of how to handle errors.

For example when I get an error String in repository class from a network call, how can I pass that to the viewModel and then to the view, and display the error?

Answer (score 1):

In MVVM architecture the ViewModel shouldn't have access to the view i.e the activity. So, for propagating error from Repo class to ViewModel, use a interface callback since the viewmodel initiates the call in repository class. Once you get the error in viewmodel use Livedata in the viewmodel and change the value. The activity can listen to the changes and act accordingly or use data binding to directly change the view from viewmodel. For the latter the Livedata can be a string and you can pass that Livedata value as a textview text. For the former the Livedata will be a boolean which on changing the activity will handle it